# Plotting a general linear model (glm) produced with the function monthglm() from the season package in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, modeling, glm

**Problem:**

I have fitted a general linear model (glm) with a categorical variable of the month using the function monthglm() based on the covariates of **Month** and **Season**, which was written by  [Barnett, A.G., Dobson, A.J. (2010) Analysing Seasonal Health Data. Springer.](http://https:/https://rdrr.io/cran/season/man/monthglm.html)

The covariates **'Month'** and **'Season'** appear to confuse the model. From looking at the **model summary (see below)**, there are some warning “Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)”, and therefore, there are exactly three months that have not been properly estimated (e.g. March, September, and December), and instead, the model output shows **NA's**. So essentially the model can’t distinguish between the covariates **Month** and **Season** because they are so similar.

I was wondering if anyone can please help in regards to **manipulating the data** or **the model itself** so the **function monthglm()** is able to calculate the mean values and upper and lower confidence levels for all blue whale sightings over all months while including the covariates **'Month'** and **'Season'** in the model? As a result, the plotted model (see below) has three missing confidence bars for March, September, and December.

**Aim**

To plot the results of the model displaying all months between January-December showing mean blue whale sightings with both upper and lower confidence levels using the covariates **'Month'** and **'Season'.**

Thank you if anyone is able to help!

**Function: monthglm():**

```
     ##Install pacakages

     library(season)
     library(MASS) # for mvrnorm
     library(survival) # for coxph
     library(ggplot2)

    ##R-code for the function monthglm2()
    
    
    monthglm2<-function(formula,data,family=gaussian(),refmonth=1,
                       monthvar='month',offsetmonth=FALSE,offsetpop=NULL){
      ## checks
      if (refmonth<1|refmonth>12){stop("Reference month must be between 1 and 12")}
      ## original call with defaults (see amer package)
      ans <- as.list(match.call())

  frmls <- formals(deparse(ans[[1]]))
  add <- which(!(names(frmls) %in% names(ans)))
  call<-as.call(c(ans, frmls[add]))

  monthvar=with(data,get(monthvar))
  cmonthvar=class(monthvar)
  ## If month is a character, create the numbers
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('factor','character')){
    if(cmonthvar=='character'){
      if(max(nchar(monthvar))==3){mlevels=substr(month.name,1,3)}else{mlevels=month.name}
      monthvar=factor(monthvar,levels=mlevels)
    }
    months=as.numeric(monthvar)
    data$month=months # add to data for flagleap
    months=as.factor(months)
    levels(months)[months]<-month.abb[months]
    months<-relevel(months,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month ### TYPO HERE, changed from months.u
  }
  ## Transform month numbers to names
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('integer','numeric')){
    months.u<-as.factor(monthvar)
    nums<-as.numeric(nochars(levels(months.u))) # Month numbers
    levels(months.u)[nums]<-month.abb[nums]
    months<-relevel(months.u,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month
  }
  ## prepare data/formula
  parts<-paste(formula)
  f<-as.formula(paste(parts[2],parts[1],parts[3:length(formula)],'+months'))
  dep<-parts[2] # dependent variable
  days<-flagleap(data=data,report=FALSE,matchin=T) # get the number of days in each month
  l<-nrow(data)
  if(is.null(offsetpop)==FALSE){poff=with(data,eval(offsetpop))} else{poff=rep(1,l)} #
  if(offsetmonth==TRUE){moff=days$ndaysmonth/(365.25/12)} else{moff=rep(1,l)} # days per month divided by average month length
  ###  data$off<-log(poff*moff)
  off<-log(poff*moff)  #
  fit<-glm(formula=f,data=data,family=family,offset=off)
  ## return
  toret<-list()
  toret$call<-call
  toret$glm<-fit
  toret$fitted.values<-fitted(fit)
  toret$residuals<-residuals(fit)
  class(toret)<-'monthglm'
  return(toret)
}
```

**Model**

```
Sightings$year <- Sightings$Year

model<-monthglm2(formula=Frequency_Blue_Whales_Year_Month~Year+Season, family=poisson(),  
                offsetmonth=TRUE, monthvar='Month', refmonth=1, data=Sightings)
```

**Model Output**

```
Call:  glm(formula = f, family = family, data = data, offset = off)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)          Year  SeasonSpring  SeasonSummer  Seasonwinter  SeasonWinter     monthsFeb     monthsMar     monthsApr     monthsMay  
  -323.25725       0.16196       0.43926      -0.03365       0.76373       0.91534      -0.06261            NA      -0.23382       0.27876  
   monthsJun     monthsJul     monthsAug     monthsSep     monthsOct     monthsNov     monthsDec  
    -1.97313     -19.55938       0.25231      -1.94416       0.00643       0.77171            NA  

Degrees of Freedom: 35 Total (i.e. Null);  21 Residual
Null Deviance:      940.7 
Residual Deviance: 195.4    AIC: 386.7
```

**summary(model)**

```
Number of observations = 36 
Rate ratios 
                  mean      lower     upper      zvalue       pvalue
monthsFeb 9.393137e-01 0.67978181 1.2979315 -0.37944839 7.043549e-01
monthsApr 7.915059e-01 0.54509500 1.1493073 -1.22869325 2.191868e-01
monthsMay 1.321488e+00 0.83554494 2.0900500  1.19180025 2.333396e-01
monthsJun 1.390209e-01 0.03860611 0.5006151 -3.01844013 2.540796e-03
monthsJul 3.202360e-09 0.00000000       Inf -0.01615812 9.871082e-01
monthsAug 1.286991e+00 1.01676543 1.6290337  2.09823277 3.588459e-02
monthsSep 1.431068e-01 0.05831898 0.3511647 -4.24489759 2.186933e-05
monthsOct 1.006450e+00 0.73231254 1.3832102  0.03963081 9.683875e-01
monthsNov 2.163470e+00 1.64625758 2.8431777  5.53616916 3.091590e-08
```

**Plot**

```
plot(model, ylim=c(0,1.4))
```

**Error message inserting the y-labels and x-labels**

```
##I am also unable to plot the x-labels and the y-labels

plot(model, 
+      ylim=c(0,1.4),
+ ylab="Mean Blue Whale Sightings", 
+ xlab="Month")
Error in plot.default(order, toplot$mean, xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

**Plotted Figure**

[image]

**Dataframe (called Sightings)**

```
    structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L), Month = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "December", "Feb", "Jan", 
"July", "June", "Mar", "May", "November", "October", "September"
), class = "factor"), Frequency_Blue_Whales_Year_Month = c(76L, 
78L, 66L, 28L, 54L, 37L, 39L, 31L, 88L, 46L, 23L, 54L, 5L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 22L, 6L, 44L, 10L, 30L, 35L, 88L, 
41L, 35L, 4L, 30L, 43L, 65L, 43L, 90L), Season = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Autumn", "Spring", "Summer", "winter", 
"Winter"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Comment: I would have expected, and your results seem to confirm, that once you specify a month that the season is completely determined. This create perfect collinearity and that is detected by the regression code and the redundant terms are dropped. Pretty sure this must be a duplicate. You can search on `multicollinearity` either on SO or on CrssValidated.com

Comment: Hi IRTFM. Thank you for your comments. Yes! You are totally right! This is an example of multicollinearity. Would you suggest that I conducted a separate analysis for year and season and a different analysis for year and month? If you were undertaking this type of analysis, would you have any suggestions with how you would approach this problem? Thank you for any advice you can give.

Comment: Actually I would think of doing neither a fixed season definition (which would suffer because of arbitrary choices of season boundary nor a month-by-month analysis (which would would require 11 degrees of freedom), but rather a couple of analyses: 1) a "sinusoidal analysis" that would allow there to be exactly two degrees of freedom: period and shift. 2) and a "band analysis" (not sure of the right term) that would allow one or more adjacent months to have a notch or a plateau in counts. Suspect this has been discussed on CrossValidated.com.